# Can't delete an item from an array with Vue and Vuex

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am working on a website with Vue and Vuex and I've got a `selected` state which contains
the selected sensors plus the selected device ids and looks like this:

```
{
    "device-id": [
        {id: "sensor-id", type: "sensor type"},
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

in the mutation for unselecting/removing the sensor I've got this at the moment:

```
// unselect sensor
let updatedSensors = state.selected[deviceId].slice();
console.log(updatedSensors);
console.log(i);
updatedSensors.splice(i, 1);
console.log(updatedSensors);
Vue.delete(state.selected[deviceId], i);

Vue.set(state.selected, deviceId, updatedSensors);
```

in this example, I am doing the same thing twice once using `set` and once using `delete` this way it does not deselect the sensor at all and console logs are kind of strange, here is a screenshot:

[image]

you see that the second console log say `(2)` 2 items but it actually has 3 items which is odd. My guess here is that `slice` and `splice` do not work through the `Vuex` proxies which is one of the reasons I've done `Vue.delete` but it also does not work even if I only use `Vue.delete`. I've tried some magic with `.filter` but it also does not work. I've searched online for answers but found nothing. Afaik, the standard way here is to use `Vue.delete`.

Comment: can you make a codesandbox so we can see a bit more context?